# is it possible to call lua functions defined in other lua scripts in redis?

Tags: node.js, lua, redis

I have tried to declare a function without the local keyword and then call that function from anther script but it gives me an error when I run the command.

```
test = function ()    
    return 'test'
end



# from some other script
test()
```

Edit:

I can't believe I still have no answer to this. I'll include more details of my setup.

I am using node with the redis-scripto package to load the scripts into redis. Here is an example.

```
var Scripto = require('redis-scripto');
var scriptManager = new Scripto(redis);

scriptManager.loadFromDir('./lua_scripts');

var keys    = [key1, key2];
var values  = [val];

scriptManager.run('run_function', keys, values, function(err, result) {
console.log(err, result)
})
```

And the lua scripts.

```
-- ./lua_scripts/dict_2_bulk.lua

-- turns a dictionary table into a bulk reply table
dict2bulk = function (dict)
    local result = {}
    for k, v in pairs(dict) do
        table.insert(result, k)
        table.insert(result, v)
    end
    return result
end


-- run_function.lua 

return dict2bulk({ test=1 })
```

Throws the following error.

```
[Error: ERR Error running script (call to f_d06f7fd783cc537d535ec59228a18f70fccde663): @enable_strict_lua:14: user_script:1: Script attempted to access unexisting global variable 'dict2bulk' ] undefined
```

Comment: I'll ask the obvious: in the second script, do you (or anywhere else) 'require' the script that specifies the function?  That is, does that code actually run?

Comment: The scripts are loaded into redis via the script load command. There is no requires from within the scripts themselves. Do I need them?

Comment: if I use require, it gives me an error. Script attempted to access unexisting global variable 'require'. I'm not sure require will work from within Redis.

Comment: Also, the script runs. I can run normal redis commands that execute successfully but it doesn't know anything about the functions that I have declared in other scripts.

Comment: @Nathan, can you please tell me how I am supposed to use require inside Redis when there is no filesystem?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that Redis didn't allow the use of require. But your code should work as long as the script that creates the function is being called. Have you confirmed that it is?

Comment: Nothing I have tried works. I tried to keep this a redis specific question but maybe I need to include more details on the redis client.

Comment: This is probably the case. If you can confirm that the scripts are running, and in the correct order, then it has to be a redis issue. Definitely include some more details about that, but I, personally, have no redis knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Important Notice:** See Josiah's answer below. My answer turns out to be **wrong** or at the least **incomplete**. Which makes me very happy ofcourse, it makes Redis all the more flexible.

**My incorrect/incomplete answer:**

I'm quite sure this is not possible. You are not allowed to use global variables (read the [docs](http://redis.io/commands/eval) ), and the script itself gets a local and temporary scope by the Redis Lua engine.

Lua functions automatically set a 'writing' flag behind the scenes if they do any write action. This starts a transaction. If you cascade Lua calls, the bookkeeping in Redis would become very cumbersome, especially when the cascade is executed on a Redis slave. That's why `EVAL` and `EVALSHA` are intentionally not made available as valid Redis calls inside a Lua script. Same goes for calling an already 'loaded' Lua function which you are trying to do. What would happen if the slave is rebooted between the load of the first script and the exec of the second script?

What we do to overcome this limitation:

Don't use `EVAL`, only use `SCRIPT LOAD` and `EVALSHA`.
Store the SHA1 inside a redis hash set.

We automated this in our versioning system, so a committed Lua script automatically gets it's SHA1 checksum stored in the Redis master, in a hash set, with a logical name. The clients can't use EVAL (on a slave; we disabled EVAL+LOAD in config). But the client can ask for the SHA1 for the next step. Almost all our Lua functions return a SHA1 for the next call.

Hope this helps, TW

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "But the client can ask for the SHA1 for the next step" or "for the next call". So what I'm hearing is that you can't run scripts from within scripts but you can use EVALSHA outside of the scripts? How does this help?

Comment: It helps in running a centralized tested unit of code. Which might be a different thing from what you are after, I'm not sure. I do hope I made clear that the Lua script has to be functional 'on it's own'. That's by design (and quite beautiful in my opinion). Redis Lua is not meant to be a codebase.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just had some methods that are used for formatting the response and wanted to reuse them in other scripts. Looks like I will need to duplicate the functions.

Comment: You're welcome, and that's correct. It might not seem "nice" from a programmer's point of view, but if you look at it from a distributed transactional NoSql point of view, it makes a lot of sense. And it's very powerful, you can 'slave' your logic all around the web. I can recommend source control automation for these kind of issues, if it suits the scope/size of your project. In generic NoSql terms: denormalisation is very common. Here you can see it applies to source code as well.

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to be contrary to the accepted answer, because the accepted answer is wrong.

While you can't explicitly define named functions, you *can* call any script that you can call with `EVALSHA`. More specifically, all of the Lua scripts that you have explicitly defined via `SCRIPT LOAD` or implicitly via `EVAL` are available in the global Lua namespace at `f_<sha1 hash>` (until/unless you call `SCRIPT FLUSH`), which you can call any time.

The problem that you run into is that the functions are defined as taking no arguments, and the `KEYS` and `ARGV` tables are actually globals. So if you want to be able to communicate between Lua scripts, you either need to mangle your `KEYS` and `ARGV` tables, or you need to use the standard Redis keyspace for communication between your functions.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> script load "return {KEYS[1], ARGV[1]}"
"d006f1a90249474274c76f5be725b8f5804a346b"
127.0.0.1:6379> eval "return f_d006f1a90249474274c76f5be725b8f5804a346b()" 1 "hello" "world"
1) "hello"
2) "world"
127.0.0.1:6379> eval "KEYS[1] = 'blah!'; return f_d006f1a90249474274c76f5be725b8f5804a346b()" 1 "hello" "world"
1) "blah!"
2) "world"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

All of this said, this is in complete violation of spec, and is entirely possible to stop working in strange ways if you attempt to run this in a Redis cluster scenario.

Comment: Hi Josiah, excellent news. _complete violation of spec_ worries me a bit, but I'll give it some thought. It doesn't really surprise me that I didn't know about this, since it's completely undocumented. Well, except for the Redis source code itself ofcourse.

Comment: Well, the trick is that the spec doesn't specify much about what actually goes on under the covers, just some things that you should and shouldn't do. It says nothing about the function being available, where the arguments are stored, etc., despite it being unchanged since the 2.4 branch with scripting from a couple years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm not one to leave well enough alone, I built a package that allows for simple internal calling semantics. The package (for Python) is available [on GitHub](http://github.com/josiahcarlson/lua-call/).

Long story short, it uses `ARGV` as a call stack, translates `KEYS`/`ARGV` references to `_KEYS` and `_ARGV`, uses Redis as a name -> hash mapping internally, and translates `CALL.<name>(<keys>, <argv>)` to a table append + Redis lookup + Lua function call.

The `METHOD.txt` file describes what goes on, and all of the regular expressions I used to translate the Lua scripts are available in `lua_call.py`. Feel free to re-use my semantics.

The use of the function registry makes this *very* unlikely to work in Redis cluster or any other multi-shard setup, but for single-master applications, it should work for the foreseeable future.